# How to use the verbal phrase "take place"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to use the verb phrase "take place" with "the video" or "the documentary" or "the film" for a subject, just like "the story" or "the scene"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To *take place [somewhere]* means "to be set or situated in that location".  With something like a movie or a novel, you would use this to describe the location for the *story*, not where the movie was filmed or the novel was written.

> Most of the movie *Titanic* **takes place** aboard the titular ocean liner, which, historically, did hit an iceberg and sink on April 15th, 1912.

In terms of media, *take place* is generally used for *fictional* stories.  In documentaries, because the story is the same as the actual events, we would instead say it is *filmed in* (or *filmed at* or *filmed on location in/at*) some area.

With fictional movies (and other stories) you can be specific and say a particular scene *takes place* in some location.

> The opening scene of *Titanic* **takes place** on the docks at Southampton, England, about 60 miles from London.

Otherwise, as FumbleFingers points out, events like concerts, competitions, political rallies, etc. can *take place* at a certain location or venue.

Comment: I wouldn't say things that "take place" are particularly likely to be *fictional* - it's perfectly natural to say that [***elections***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22elections+take+place%22) or [***the World Cup***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22world+cup+takes+place%22) take place at specified intervals / locations. It's more a matter of saying that we don't normally speak of ***documentaries*** "taking place" in that way.